# xcode 4 product still in red

Tags: xcode, product

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.app file appears in red (missing) in new projects with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409015/app-file-appears-in-red-missing-in-new-projects-with-xcode-4)

XCode 4 : Product still appearing in red … myAppName.app under Products ??

Under XCode Preferences:Locations I see for Build “Place build products in derived data location (recommended)”.  “Unique subfolder” list item is checked.

Going to Folder: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, I then build fresh and see:
myAppName-bqxvzqesjyqjhlgzhainyxexzacq Folder : 
    Build Folder : 
        Products Folder : 
            Debug-iphonesimulator Folder : 
                myApp
                myApp.app. dSYM

Under Project Settings, I have Application Target = iPhone, so it makes sense that the folder one down from Products Folder starts with the name: Debug-iphonesimulator.  I suspect the prefix “Debug” comes from the Code Signing Identity = iPhone Developer, versus iPhone Distribution.

Then, I reset Locations under Preferences to “Place build products in locations specified by targets”

At this point a build Folder appears in my app’s Project Folder, which it’s supposed to; however, the Debug-iphonesimulator Folder also shows up again in the above Project Folder.

To make matters worse, myAppName.app still shows in red ??

Comment: I have a similar problem. There are still some bugs in some of the new file resolution features. The product is being built, and it's where you expect it, but Xcode doesn't know where it is. There seem to be some combinations of preferences which cause problems. I've hacked mine to put all products in one directory, the same as with Xcode 3, because I don't use workspaces for everything, and need to link to common frameworks in a central location. But sometimes projects see their own products, and other times they don't.

Answer (score 3):

Put the app in iOS Device mode, then click Product -> Build For -> Archiving

This should work

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the product in release mode. This could be a duplicate - or at least very similar to the question [Xcode product in red when in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238612/xcode-product-in-red-when-in-release-mode)