# Xcode product in red when in release mode

Tags: xcode, distribution

I want to distribute my app, i put code signing and everything and my last step was to set the build to release. I went  to edit scheme and put build configuration to release and then my product turned red for some reason. I couldnt open it in finder therefore i cant send it. If I change it back to build mode it isnt red and I can open it in finder. What do I do?

I have tried heaps of things but cannot get it to work!

Please help,

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to need to build you product on release mode. Change the build configuration as you made and build, exactly the same way you did in debug mode.

In Xcode 4 and older 3.x version, however, you probably shouldn't build directly in release mode but use the [archive feature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/SCM/SCM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH7-SW21).

Comment: i did, read the question, i changed the scheme to release mode

Comment: how do i change  my product mode

Comment: `I went to edit scheme and put build configuration to release and then my product turned red for some reason.` You didn't said that you actually build your project, Xcode doesn't do it automatically. Anyway, have you tried archiving?

Comment: oh i understand what you mean, ok

Comment: what i did was went to product and pressed build for archive and its not red

Comment: No problem, and welcome to StackOverflow. Since it resolved you problem you can accept my answer and/or up vote it.