# Why my XCode unit test does not work at all?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I created a empty test project (static library type) with enabling the unit test.

But after that the product of the unit test is red as shown on the picture below.

Also I can't find a schema for the test and I can't even run the test.

Any one can help me out?

[image: xcode unit test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press and hold the run button and select test. Or go Product>Test from the toolbar. It will then build your target you want to test and run the tests on that.

Comment: Can I know what does the red color mean? means problems about product?

Comment: The red means that it hasn't been built and doesn't exist yet. For example if you are developing a mac app that produces a .app or a framework you can right click and show in finder to see the produced build. If it is red these haven't been created yet.

Comment: but the thing is that the two items in my example are still red and I can test them.

Comment: Seems it needs to be built in release mode. Here is a question dealing with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396749/xcode-4-product-still-in-red