# How to resolve the issue .app is in red color in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am facing very critical problem in the last point of uploading app to app store.When i saw the .app file under the Products folder it shows as an missing state..I followed lots solutions but any one is working for me..([xcode 4 product still in red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396749/xcode-4-product-still-in-red)) this is also not worked for me..Please give me a solution

Comment: So ? Create archive then open Organizer and you can export it from there

Comment: It means build is not getting created. What errors are you shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select menu option Product->Archive to build the archive that you can then submit for appstore approval.

Comment: Yes i solve that issue