# Product file missing in xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging, product

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.app file appears in red (missing) in new projects with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409015/app-file-appears-in-red-missing-in-new-projects-with-xcode-4)

When I build my app in xcode 4 the product folder has a red myAppName.app and I can't get to it, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to your clean build folder by pressing Command + Option + Shift + K