# Cant figure out why my Product.app is red

Tags: iphone, xcode, .app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.app file appears in red (missing) in new projects with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409015/app-file-appears-in-red-missing-in-new-projects-with-xcode-4)

I just upgraded to XCODE 4.1, upgraded to OS Lion, had to replace my expired developer and distribution and team certificates. Now my Product AppName.app appears red. The app compiles file with no errors using Base SDK IOS 4.3 and tests fine in the simulator and on the iPhone device.
I've used Product>Clean, rebuilt it many times but the AppName.app remains red.
Any help is appreciated.
lq

Comment: if you have built it w/o error, sometimes restarting Xcode fixes it. otherwise, the mistakes i make is that i have to choose the right scheme or recreate the scheme in case it's been removed or hidden.

Comment: I've restarted, rebooted, let it sit hoping external forces would fix it. Still no go. I don't know what you mean by choose the right scheme.

Comment: reboot should not be necessary. your project has one scheme per target by default. you can add schemes or choose schemes of your dependencies in Xcode. if you have never created a scheme, your project has only one target (Product.app), and your project does not reference other projects (e.g. does not link to static libraries) then you *should* still be using the default scheme. you choose the scheme using the tabbed popup in the upper left (e.g. where you would specify device or simulator) -- the default scheme has the same title as your product name. (cont)

Comment: (cont) one way to verify that there is one scheme in your project is by going to "Manage Schemes" (cmd+shift+, - then click "Manage Schemes…").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay this is what you do quite simply:

1. make sure you downloaded your developer profile matching your bundle id and select it in targets or project settings
2. Then MAKE SURE YOU SET YOUR build to release (EDIT SCHEME)
3. go to product and go to build for and then build for archiving

shouldnt be red

Comment: Build for Archiving is greyed out (unavailable)

Comment: I set my build to release (EDIT SCHEME)

Comment: Figured it out from another post: In the scheme drop down you have to choose an actual device, not one of the simulators. Thanks. You got me 75% there.

Comment: oh yeh sorry forgot that