# Xcode: products in red

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.app file appears in red (missing) in new projects with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409015/app-file-appears-in-red-missing-in-new-projects-with-xcode-4)

Since I've installed Xcode 4.2, products are in red even if I create an empty application with a template and I Build and Run it.

I don't remember that this was the default behaviour.

Comment: did you check the base sdk, is it set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always showing up as red for me as well. It doesn't really matter, because you get access to the build products through the Organiser in Xcode 4

Comment: I beg to differ. That's what this **Products** section is for: avoid the Organizer. Fix at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16462217/218152.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. Right click the product and select Show in Finder. If it appears in Finder it is a bug. It doesn't matter though, it's purely visual. I saw that happening a few times.

Comment: It doesn't appear when i click show in finder