# Why are my targets in Products colored red?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.app file appears in red (missing) in new projects with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409015/app-file-appears-in-red-missing-in-new-projects-with-xcode-4)

With seemingly no provocation, the three .app entries in the Products folder of my hierachy are listed in red. Show In Finder is greyed out when I right click them, even if I build them first (and building is successful, no errors).

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: I've never had XCode behaving any differently to that...

Comment: Interesting. Red indicates that they can't be found, though, right?

Comment: AFAIK yes. But I don't know where XCode looks for them. I find them in the due place, in the derived data folder.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about iOS apps:

Xcode shows only the .app built for the device in the Products folder. So if you clean the product and then build for Simulator, it will still be red. If you build for the device, Xcode will show it and "show in finder" also works.