# Xcode iOS Share Extension: Why is .appex file marked red?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension

I'm new to Xcode and I would like to build a simple `iOS 8 Share Extension`.
I used [this tutorial](http://easynativeextensions.com/how-to-list-air-app-in-ios-share-menu/) but after building the extension the 3 files under `Products` are all marked red instead of black.
This is how it should be:

[image]

What does it mean if they are marked in red?

Comment: possibly duplcated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409015 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754880

Comment: Thank you, I didn't found those threads.