# How To Create New Swift File?

Tags: xcode

I am Trying to create a new Swift File (`UIViewController`) to link it  to a a viewController in the Interface Builder.
I have chosen cocoa touch class / Swift as a language. However, when the created, it's appearing red texted, with a greyed out icon, when click it nothing happened or displays "no editor". I expect to see the code / imports.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

File -> New -> File -> Swift File

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways to add Swift file to your existing project:

1. File – New – File... – `Swift File`
2. `RMB` in Project Navigator – New File – `Swift File`
3. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> – `Swift File`

All three must work as expected. If not, restart Xcode and create a project from scratch.

Comment: I have been doing 2. I have just restarted Xcode, and attempted 1 and 3. The file is created, but the text is red, their is no code view, and when clicked on displays "no editor"

Comment: @uwotm8 Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409015/app-file-appears-in-red-missing-in-new-projects-with-xcode-4

Comment: Although, there are some discrepancies between Xcode 4 and Xcode 8.